# Running .NetCore API on IIS 403 Forbidden

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I can't seem to get my netcore api up and running on IIS.

I'm deploying from Azure DevOps

- The files from the build artifact are present on the remote server though I ran build and not publish, but it seems like everything is there.
- I've created an Application Pool with `No Managed Code` in the .Net CLR Version,
- I've given permissions to the `wwroot/api` directory for read/write/execute to IIS_IUSRS
- I've installed the AspNetCoreModuleV2 and restarted the service(s)

If I add an `index.html` file to the site I won't get the 403. Makes sense.

If I enabled directory browsing I can see all of my files.

There aren't any views for the site, it's just a headless API. I'm not sure if there's anything else that I need to make sure is added/installed for it to run.

Thoughts?

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web API is in general not to be accessed via a browser, so any 403 error is expected. You should roll back all unnecessary changes and test it with a tool like Postman.

Comment: That makes sense. I was trying with postman before. Apparently it seems like there's an issue connecting to my database server at moment. Once that is resolved I think everything will be fine. I also see an error in post man with the domain not being found, which is kind of odd.